# How to add Linqpad Extension with existing code

Tags: linqpad

I am interested in exporting a SQL `SELECT` statement to a list of `INSERT` statements. I found a block of code [here](https://gist.github.com/praschl/30a8eeebe886812a1ffe09bfbb5aa81e) that is described as

> LINQPad Extensions to generate Class and Insert Statements from SQL

However, I'm not sure how to begin using this in Linqpad. I thought I would just need to copy and paste the code into the "My Extensions" area in Linqpad but that doesn't seem to be working.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a query using your database connection. Set your query mode to Program.

Append the code after the "Define other methods" comment. Add a line to `Main` to generate the code and output it:

```
CSharpClassFromSqlGeneratorExtensions.DumpInsert(this.Connection, "SELECT * from Accounts").Dump();
```

or

```
CSharpClassFromSqlGeneratorExtensions.DumpClass(this.Connection, "SELECT * from [User]").Dump();
```

Copy the output into another query.

I don't find the output very useful when I look at it, however.

Comment: Got it, thanks. I can't get it to display an output so I guess that's not the best code to use but your technique worked fine.

Comment: Never mind, I got it to create an output now and I see what you mean. Thanks again.

Comment: @BarrettNashville Perhaps you can ask your original question again with more detail on the `SELECT` and `INSERT` and get help with the translation.